# SQL Server returns nothing if lock on row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query that locks specific rows related to a table value list of parent PKs.

Locking query:

```
SELECT COUNT(PK) 
FROM tasks WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) 
WHERE parent_PK IN (SELECT * FROM @parentPKS);
```

I'm trying to make a query that I can then run when the locking query is out that will return all the rows that aren't locked that fit the criteria.

Checking query:

```
SELECT COUNT(PK) 
FROM tasks WITH (...) 
WHERE parent_PK in (SELECT * FROM @parentPKS);
```

For instance, if I have 4 tasks that are in the tasks table; two related to parent_PK **1**, two related to parent_PK **2**.

Table example:

| PK | name | parent_PK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "Task 1" | 1 |
| 2 | "Task 2" | 1 |
| 3 | "Task 3" | 2 |
| 4 | "Task 4" | 2 |

When I run the locking query: `where parent_PK in (1)` it will return 2. Since two tasks fit the criteria, so I know these rows are locked.

In the checking query, if I again run `where for parent_PK in (1)`, I want a query that will return 0 as they are already locked.

I don't exactly know if this exists but thought I'd ask, thank you.

Comment: Why are you using those hints at all? What actual problem is this trying to solve? You assume it can be solved with lock hints (probably not), but didn't explain what the actual problem is. Are you trying to create checkout/checkin logic? You can't do it with long-lived locks and transactions, that only creates blocking and deadlocks.

Comment: Yassou. Its to solve a concurrency issue. Essentially a race condition is occurring so I'm putting a lock on the tasks that are being edited during a transaction. I just need a query that I can run in another transaction to check if the rows are locked without waiting for them to be unlocked.

Comment: You keep describing your attempted solution, not the problem. Databases have no race conditions, "clever" code does. Transactions already ensure consistency *at the serialization level they use*.  Locks in databases have very specific uses. They're neither a Mutex nor a checkout nor a queueing mechanism

Comment: Trying to make the database work like a single-threaded application causes serious performance problems and possibly deadlocking as well. If you want to make a table work like a queue, you can do so for *very* specific queries, using very specific lock hints. Even then, you risk delaying the entire application if multiple connections are forced to wait one after the other to retrieve data. That's why SQL Server has the Message Broker system

Comment: Yes, the code has a race condition though it is quite hard to explain. I understand it may have issues but at this point, I essentially just need a way to know if a row lock is on specific rows.

Comment: `I'm putting a lock on the tasks that are being edited during a transaction` you don't have to do that at all. That's what a transaction does already. When you call `UPDATE`, the affected rows get an Exclusive lock for as long as the transaction is active. `WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)` takes the same locks

Comment: The code *causes* a race condition because it tries to second-guess the database. You need to fix that code. What does that code do? Perhaps you're using separate SELECT and UPDATE statements instead of a single UPDATE to modify rows. Perhaps you're using a cursor. Perhaps you're loading the data in the client for processing, and try to use database locks as a checkout mechanism. That's not what database locks are for

Comment: The transaction is long and many updates occur throughout. Before anything is updated I'm locking these rows in the transaction at the beginning so that if another process comes along that overlaps it stops and waits.